# How to pass click event from custom action bar to current page of android ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an `Activity` with `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` and custom `ActionBar`. There are three(0,1,2) pages in the `ViewPager` with page 1 set to be default page and user can slide left and right.
One Fragment class is used to show UI for each of the pages,which has a `WebView` which shows some html data which can be collapsed and viewed on a `Button` click in the `WebView`. Now there is also a button in the action, and I'm required to collapse and show these data on `WebView`on the click of the `Button` in `ActionBar`. I've done it but the problem is that the items on the currently viewing page of `ViewPager` are not toggling on the click of the button in the actionbar, while that for the page on the left or right of it are working well.
How can I solve this problem?
What is the correct method of doing this?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you should implement a listener interface for the page you want to listen to the action bar events and execute the method on the click of the click event. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to write 3 interfaces in 3 fragments.
2. You need to register this 3 fragments to you pager adapter/activity.
3. Whenever you click on the actionBar button check which is your
   active/current page in the viewPager.
4. Perform click operation on the registered interface on the basis of
   the active/current Page/Fragment.

Comment: I've only one fragment class which is added to each page of view pager with different data from database.

Comment: Please edit your question. It is not clear. In question you are saying each fragment that means you have multiple fragments. Here is your statement "Each fragment has a webview which shows some html data which can be collapsed and viewed on a button click in the webview"